# Parse String in C# to find code for an HTML Element

Tags: c#

I need to parse a string in C# to find out code for a Particular HTML element with a given ID.

For Example:

I have a string with complete source code of a URL in it. How can I parse the string to find the inner HTML of an element of a given ID say 1,2,3...

Comment: @P.S. I'm not sure why your edit was approved, it was too minor. Try to make more substantive edits in the future.

Comment: @2rs2ts I did so to make question more clear in first look.I highlight the main point of question i.e. what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use a third party HTML parser like [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

Don't write one yourself.

Example usage:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Src: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Comment: There is an error in example on the foreach line, but I can't edit it as the edit is less than six characters. The closing quote and closing square bracket are the wrong way round. Also there is a missing closing parenthesis at the end of the line.